# Is it natural to use the possessive adjective in "their olive trees"?

Tags: possessives, writing, determiners

Does the following sentence sound natural?

> 1. They harvest their olive trees in autumn.

Can I say: *their* olive trees or does it sound more natural without "their"?

> 2. They harvest olive trees in autumn.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the sentence with 'their' or without. It depends if you want to emphasize that the trees they are harvesting belong to them (with their) or not (without their).

Comment: Side note: 'To harvest' is 'to gather in crops', in this instance, unless you are cutting the trees down to harvest the wood (which it would be tricky to do *every* autumn), the crop is the olives. Therefore they harvest olives, not olive trees.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both in this case. However, they are slightly different.

> 1. They harvest olive trees in autumn.

This implies that "they" harvest all olive trees in autumn. That is to say, if I asked "them" when I should harvest my olive trees, they would tell me to do it in autumn because they think that's when you should do it.

> 2. They harvest their olive trees in autumn.

This version, however, could still allow for a situation where the ideal time to harvest trees (according to "them") is e.g. summer, but that "they" still harvest **their** trees in autumn for whatever reason.

Technically, (1) addresses **all** olive trees. But you can automatically infer that you are only talking about the trees that "they" have access to.
(2) on the other hand specifically talks about **their** olive trees. It creates a bigger implication that someone else might do it differently.

Both sentences mean the same thing when used to state the fact of when they will harvest. But based on the two options, you can imply that all olive trees should be harvested in autumn anyway (1) or that "they" (and *only* them, if you imply it) harvest their olive trees in autumn (2).

Another example:

> I drive a car like a maniac.
>   I drive my car like a maniac.

The second sentence leaves it open whether or not I would drive *your* car like a maniac. I am seemingly implying that I *only* drive *my* car like a maniac. Although that is not a guaranteed implication.

**Note** Even if I used the second sentence, that does not definitively mean that I would *not* drive *your* car like a maniac. I'm talking about implications here, not stated facts.
If you do not scrutinize for (potentially unintended) implications, then the sentences mean the same thing.

Comment: Huh? If I say "I saw rabbits in the yard today", it certainly doesn't mean that I saw ***all*** rabbits. There's no reason (1) needs to mean ***all*** olive trees, although it could.

Comment: @PeterShor: But when you say "Rabbits eat carrots", you are saying that **all** rabbits eat carrots. "There are rabbits" is not the same as using "Rabbits" as the subject. For olive trees, it is the object; but the fact remains the same. I am not 100% sure on the exact grammatical name for "there are [plural noun]", but it is most definitely not equivalent to [plural noun] when used as a subject or object.

Comment: But when I say "Rabbits eat my carrots before I can harvest them", it doesn't mean all rabbits. And I'm using "rabbits" as the subject.

Comment: Indefinite articles inherently imply that it is irrelevant to try and distinguish between the collective term and any specific subset of that collective term. Consider the difference between "Men play sports" and "The men play sports". Neither statement definitively proves that **all** men play sports, but the first one is still considered a blanket statement. The second is not. If you disallow inference, "Men play sports" does state all men. It's just that we often automatically infer that these statement are not literal but rather indicate that it applies to a majority of men.

Comment: @PeterShor: `(1 - Peter) And I'm using "rabbits" as the subject. (2 - Flater) Indefinite articles inherently imply that ... (3 - Peter) "The" is a definite article, not an indefinite article.` You're not following the flow of conversation.